# If a specific checkbox is checked, I want to run another section of jQuery code if it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

If a specific checkbox is checked, I want to run another section of jQuery code if it is.

Here's my jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q7kq5/3/

My JS code right now is pretty simple: One for only allowing 1 checkbox to be checked, the other for validation. But I'm sure that it isn't going to cut it. Not sure where to go from there though:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Method input:checkbox").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
    $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
    }
  });
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: false,
    success: "valid"
    });
  $("#CheckOut").validate({
    rules: {
    FirstName: {
    required: true
    },
    LastName: {
    required: true
    },
    Email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
    },
    Phone: {
    required: true,
    digits:true
    },
    Address1: {
    required: true
    },
    City: {
    required: true
    },
    PostalCode: {
    required: true,
    digits: true
    },
    Country: {
    required: true
    },
    State: {
    required: true
    },
    pwd: {
    required: true
    },
    pwd_confirm: {
    required: true
    },
    FName_SHIP: {
    required: true
    },
    LName_Ship: {
    required: true
    },
    Phone_Ship: {
    required: true,
    digits: true
    },
    Address1_Ship: {
    required: true
    },
    City_Ship: {
    required: true
    },
    PostalCode_SHIP: {
    required: true,
    digits: true
    },
    COUNTRY_SHIP: {
    required: true
    },
    State_SHIP: {
    required: true
    },
    NameOnCard: {
    required: true
    },
    CreditCardType: {
    required: true
    },
    CardNumber: {
    required: true,
    digits: true
    },
    CardExpMonth: {
    required: true
    },
    CardExpYear: {
    required: true
    },
    CVC: {
    required: true,
    digits: true
    }
  }
  });
});
```

What I'm looking to do: If Credit Card method is checked, use the jQuery validator JS to validate the CC fields. If On Account method is checked, use the jQuery validator JS to validate only the On Account field.

However, if one of them isn't checked, I do not want jQuery validator JS to validate those fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a javascript function that runs onclick anytime you click a checkbox and determine which checkbox is checked and then do certain logic based on that?

Like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="creditcard" id="creditcard" onclick="validate()">
<input type="checkbox" name="onaccount" id="onaccount" onclick="validate()">

function validate
{
if($("#creditcard").attr("checked"))
    {
    do credit card stuff;
    }
else if($(#onaccount).attr("checked"))
    {
    do on account stuff;
    }
else
    {
    do nothing;
    }
}
```

That's obviously rough code, but hopefully you understand what I mean!